# read data from excel file using symfony4

Tags: excel, symfony, symfony4

I have been creating web application using symfony4, I want to read data from excel file.

when I install the bundle liuggio/ExcelBundle, I get the error:

`Installation request for liuggio/excelbundle ^2.1 -> satisfiable by liuggio/ExcelBundle[v2.1.0].`

Comment: 1) That's not an error message 2) Take a look at phpExcel.

Comment: That's a composer installation conflict message, That bundle requires Symfony 2.6 or 3.x, It is not compatible with 4.x. SO is not a place to ask for software packages. With that said you don't need a Bundle to use an excel PHP library, but you could use [`XlsBundle dev-master`](https://github.com/arodiss/XlsBundle) which uses phpoffice/phpexcel.

Answer (score 1):

This error message tell you, that composer was not able to install `liuggio/excelbundle` because a viable version was not found. In other words, there is a version conflict between your composer.json and the one from the project.

From checking [the info on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/liuggio/ExcelBundle) I assume it's this part of the library's composer.json that's causing the issue:

```
 symfony/framework-bundle: ~2.6|~3.0
```

The package does not support Symfony 4's FrameworkBundle yet. It seems there is already [an open issue](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle/issues/127) on the project's Github issue tracker.

It looks like the package is no longer maintained as it uses an outdated library and instead you should switch from PHPExcel to PHPSpreadsheet, which is the same project with a new name. You might be able to find a new library for this.